# File descriptor duplication

Tags: bash, fifo, tee

I'd like to feed multiple copies of stdin to different stdins/FDs in bash.
Example:

```
for host in $hosts; do
  exec_magic_stdin_dupe {FH}
  ssh $host someProgram <&$FH
done
```

I've used GNU parallel a bit, but I've got some caveats with it and really thought this should be something bash can do alone.
The only way I've found that's anything like this is to 'tee' it with subshell replacements like:

```
tee >(ssh $hostOne someProgram) >(ssh $hostTwo someProgram) ... > /dev/null
```

But that means I've got to perform some sort of loop creating a big 'tee' command and then execute it via 'eval' (or similar).

I could do it by managing my own fifos as well, but that's not a particularly preferable solution either.

All the above can work. I just want to verify that I'm not missing some way to implement 'exec_magic_stdin' before implementing one of those solutions.

Comment: It's just a typo: duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion helps here; you can pipe the output of one `tee` into the input of the next, until you are out of hosts. Each call to `recFunc` "peels off" one host. `tee` passes its input to both a call to `ssh` and to the next invocation of `recFunc`, which does nothing if it receives no arguments. The initial call to `recFunc` gets a list of host names as arguments and its standard input from the file you want to duplicate.

```
recFunc () {
    if (( $# )); then
        tee >(ssh "$1" someProgram) | recFunc "${@:2}"
    fi
}

hosts=(hostOne hostTwo hostThree ... )
recFunc "${hosts[@]}" < inputfile
```

Comment: That is indeed a bit cleaner than looping to build a command and eval.  There's still some difficulty with the aspect of influencing the higher level shell (part of reason I failed to include is process sub puts me in a subshell and I can't influence the rest from there).  But I should probably follow this up with a more specific question about that.